# Create Progress Bar in Liferay

Tags: list, dynamic, progress-bar, liferay

I am looking to create a progress bar in Liferay, hopefully inside the Dynamic List Display plugin but not necessarily. The data for the progress bar will be coming from the List though.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This might help [Add Portlet progress bar](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+add+a+progress+bar+to+my+portlet) or else you can create your own simple implementation of a progress-bar with threading concept, javascript and ajax.

Comment: @PrakashK great! do you have any tutorial by any chance? I see that they talk about adding some code at the end of the JSP files, how do I do this? I'm new to Liferay and I don't know where the JSP files are

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/24603710
This helped me with a progress bar in one of my projects.

Comment: You can take an example of this ass well http://alloyui.com/tutorials/progress-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with AlloyUI in Liferay 6.2. You need a placeholder for the progressbar - something like this:

```
<div id="myProgressBar" style="width:100%;height:20px;"></div>
```

And then you can create it with javascript like this:

```
<aui:script use="aui-base,aui-progressbar">
var progressBar = new A.ProgressBar({
        boundingBox: '#myProgressBar',
        label: '<%=percentage%>%',
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        value: '<%=percentage%>',
    }).render();
</aui:script>
```

You can read more about the progress bar config options here:
http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.ProgressBar.html

And some samples here:
http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/tutorials/progress-bar/